# Double axis x chart in Google Sheets

Tags: charts, google-sheets

I have these columns in Google Sheets:

```
Date         Product type   Amount Sold
2019-07-01   A              15
2019-07-01   B              2
2019-07-01   C              0
2019-07-01   D              3
2019-07-02   A              8
2019-07-02   B              1
2019-07-02   C              0
2019-07-02   D              0
2019-07-03   A              7
2019-07-03   B              6
2019-07-03   C              0
2019-07-03   D              1
```

When I plot this I get

[image]

I would like to group these data by day, with column colors for each product type and the legend relating them to A, B, C, D but I cannot achieve this goal, since Product type column are not values.

Is there any way in Google Sheets to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've figured out how to do what you're trying to achieve - in order to do this I first arranged the data like this

[image: Data]

With the data range for the chart being from the row with the **Date** label to the last row of the data.

Here's how I have the chart set up in the editor

[image: Chart Setup]

The aggregate checkbox is what allows the stacked columns

Here's the series menu

[image: Series Menu]

and finally, here's the end result

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: But If I do this I will still have the date repeated

Comment: @Laura Oh my apologies, so you want it such that each letter (A,B,C,D) is stacked and a different colour from the last, with one column per day?

Comment: @Laura I changed my answer to reflect the desired result